# How to get the index of a clicked CollectionView element?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have elements added inside a `CollectionView`. Inside this `CollectionView`, I have an `ImageButton` which make visible other `ImageButton`. I need to get the index of the element by clicking the first `ImageButton` and use it in the `Command` of the second `ImageButton`. Is that possible?

My xaml:

```xml
<StackLayout>
    <CollectionView ItemSource="{Binding myItemSource}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentView>
                    <ImageButton x:Name="FirstImageButton" Command={Binding MakeVisibleNewButton}/>
                </ContentView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
    <ImageButton x:Name="SecondImageButton" Command={Binding xxxCommand} IsVisible={Binding VisibleByFirstButton} />
</StackLayout
```

Comment: you have to look up the selected item in the ItemsSource to get its index

Comment: Can you give me a sample line?

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

As Jason said,you could get the index by looking up the selected item in the ItemSource.

For example:

```
public class YourViewModel
{
   public List<yourmodel> myItemSource{ get; set; }
   public ICommand MakeVisibleNewButton{ get; set; }
    public YourViewModel()
    {
        ... //fill the myItemSource
        MakeVisibleNewButton= new Command<Productor>(ImageButtonClicked);
    }

    private void ImageButtonClicked(yourmodel obj)
    {
       int index = myItemSource.IndexOf(obj); //the index is what you want to get
    }

}
```

the xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
  <CollectionView x:Name ="collectionview" ItemSource="{Binding myItemSource}">
      <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentView>
                <ImageButton x:Name="FirstImageButton" Command="{Binding BindingContext.MakeVisibleNewButton,Source={x:Reference collectionview}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
            </ContentView>
        </DataTemplate>
      </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
   </CollectionView>
   <ImageButton x:Name="SecondImageButton" Command={Binding xxxCommand} IsVisible={Binding VisibleByFirstButton} />
</StackLayout
```